# setRingerMode() mutes MediaPlayer on tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

Android 4.2.2. On my Nexus 7 tablet, setting the ringer mode to `RINGER_MODE_SILENT` effectively mutes any active `MediaPlayer` of my activity:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Service.AUDIO_SERVICE);     
audioManager.setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

I'm convinced this is a bug. Has anybody seen this before? And more importantly, **is there a workaround**?

Comment: Is that a Wi-Fi model?

Comment: Yes, it has Wi-Fi. Don't all tablets?

Comment: I wanted to say "Wi-Fi _only_ model?", there is that 3G model also. Then I realized that that would not make any change as neither models support voice calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm convinced this is a bug

That could be intentional and I think you can check if the device supports voice calls before changing the ringer mode (after all, ringer modes are to be used for calls only?). Hence,

```
    if (isVoiceCapable(context)) {
        audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Service.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    }
```

...

```
private boolean isVoiceCapable(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephony =
            (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return telephony != null && (telephony.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE);
}
```

Hope this helps.